# When does python start using a different algorithm for big multiplication?

Tags: python, algorithm, multiplication

I'm currently in an algorithms class and was interested to see which of two methods of multiplying a list of large numbers gives the faster runtime. What I found was that the recursive multiply performs about 10x faster. For the code below, I got t_sim=53.05s and t_rec=4.73s. I did some other tests and they all seemed to be around the 10x range.

Additionally, you could put the values from the recursive multiply into a tree and reuse them to even more quickly compute multiplications of subsets of the list.

I did a theoretical runtime analysis, and both are n^2 using standard multiplication, but when the karatsuba algorithm is used, that factor goes down to n^log_2(3).

Every multiply in simple_multiply should have runtime i * 1. Summing over i=1...n, we get an arithmetic series and can use gauss's formula to get n*(n+1)/2 = O(n^2).

For the second one, we can see that the time to multiply for a given level of recursion is (2^d)^2, where d is the depth, but only needs to multiply n*2^-d values. The levels turn out to form a geometric series where the runtime at each level is n*2^d with a final depth of log_2(n). The solution to the geometric series is n * (1-2^log_2(n))/(1-2) = n*(n-1) = O(n^2). If using the karatsuba algorithm, you can get O(n^log_2(3)) by doing the same method

If the code were using the karatsuba algorithm, then the speedup would make sense, but what doesn't seem to make sense is the linear relationship between the two runtimes, making it seem like python is using standard multiplication, which according to wikipedia is faster when using under 500ish bits. (I'm using 2^23 bits in the code below. Each number is literally a megabyte long)

```
import random
import time

def simple_multiply(values):
    a = 1
    for val in values:
        a *= val
    return a

def recursive_multiply(values):
    if len(values) == 1:
        return values[0]
    temp = []
    i = 0
    while i + 1 < len(values):
        temp.append(values[i] * values[i+1])
        i += 2
    if len(values) % 2 == 1:
        temp.append(values[-1])
    return recursive_multiply(temp)

def test(func, values):
    t1 = time.time()
    func(values)
    print( time.time() - t1)

def main():
    n = 2**11
    scale = 2**12
    values = [random.getrandbits(scale) for i in range(n)]
    test(simple_multiply, values)
    test(recursive_multiply, values)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Time complexity is a purely theoretical measure – the constant factors have no relevance whatsoever. Only consider "constant factors" when benchmarking real code – don't mix the two metrics.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the range of calculation, to see if the current trend stays as is?

Comment: @don Using the values above, it's already taking a whole minute to run, so that seems infeasible

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yeah, I'm aware of that, but I think since they're both doing multiplication only (or at least dominantly), they have the same associated factors. This is making me think that different algorithms are used when python does the multiplications, in which case you're right and the factors shouldn't line up.

Comment: Just let it ran for a bit and it seems like the trend is that doubling the size means a 4x increase in time for the simple method whereas it was a 3x multiple for the recursive method. This means that method 1 is quadratic (and each multiplication is linear) while method 2 is to the power of log_2(3), the same as karatsuba's algorithm.

Comment: CPython uses Karatsuba for sufficiently large integers. See the code path starting at [`long_mul`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/longobject.c#L3548).

Comment: @user2357112 Very interesting! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both versions of the code have the same number of multiplications, but in the simple version each multiplication is ~2000 bits long on average.

In the second version n/2 multiplications are 24 bits long, n/4 are 48 bits long, n/8 are 96 bits long, etc...   The average length is only 48 bits.

Comment: Average length isn't quite the right measure to compare, since the cost of a multiplication isn't directly proportional to length, but it does give a feel for why the pairwise multiplication is cheaper.

Comment: A single multiplication takes about n^2 time, and at each level, the size is doubleing while the number off multiplications is halving, but since multiplications take n^2 time, the doubling of the size is more important than the number of multiplications. I've done some more research and updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: @BenThayer  in the simple version, each multiplication takes O(n), since one of the operands is a small constant size.  That produces O(n^2) overall.  In the recursive version, the bigger multiplications are optimized using at least Karatsuba, then maybe toom-cook, then maybe Schönhage–Strassen as they get larger

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your assumption. Your assumption is that each multiplication of the between the different ranks should take same times, for instance `len(24)*len(72)` approx `len(48)*len(48)`. But that's not true, as evident by the following snippets:

```
%%timeit
random.getrandbits(2**14)*random.getrandbits(2**14)*random.getrandbits(2**14)*random.getrandbits(2**14)

>>>1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop

%%timeit
(random.getrandbits(2**14)*random.getrandbits(2**14))*(random.getrandbits(2**14)*random.getrandbits(2**14))

>>>1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop
```

The difference is consistent even on such a small scale